# Checked Radio button inside table does not visualize

Tags: html

I have the following table with radio buttons inside a table cell.  For some reason only the last radio button actually visually is checked.

```
 <table class="QueryInfo" id="FreezerInfo">
      <thead>
           <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Used</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

           <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>20096</td>
                <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
                <td>
                     <div class="radio">
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                          </label>
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used" value="1" >Yes</input>
                          </label>

                     </div>

                </td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>20097</td>
                <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
                <td>
                     <div class="radio">
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                          </label>
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used" value="1" >Yes</input>
                          </label>

                     </div>

                </td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>20098</td>
                <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
                <td>
                     <div class="radio">
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                          </label>
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used" value="1" >Yes</input>
                          </label>

                     </div>

                </td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>20099</td>
                <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
                <td>
                     <div class="radio">
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                          </label>
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used" value="1" >Yes</input>
                          </label>

                     </div>

                </td>
           </tr>


           <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>20100</td>
                <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
                <td>
                     <div class="radio">
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                          </label>
                          <label class="radio-inline">
                               <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used" value="1" >Yes</input>
                          </label>

                     </div>

                </td>
           </tr>

      </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is an example of what I'm seeing https://jsfiddle.net/3aj4azkj/1/

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because names of all radio boxes are same. Change the name of each set. 
See code snippet.

```html
<table class="QueryInfo" id="FreezerInfo">
     <thead>
          <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>Number</th>
               <th>Time</th>
               <th>Used</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>

          <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>20096</td>
               <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
               <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                         </label>
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used" value="1" >Yes</input>
                         </label>

                    </div>

               </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>20097</td>
               <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
               <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used1" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                         </label>
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used1" value="1" >Yes</input>
                         </label>

                    </div>

               </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>20098</td>
               <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
               <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used2" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                         </label>
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used2" value="1" >Yes</input>
                         </label>

                    </div>

               </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>20099</td>
               <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
               <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used3" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                         </label>
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used3" value="1" >Yes</input>
                         </label>

                    </div>

               </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>20100</td>
               <td>2016-09-27 10:13:48</td>
               <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_no' name="used4" value="0"  checked >No</input>
                         </label>
                         <label class="radio-inline">
                              <input type="radio" id='used_yes' name="used4" value="1" >Yes</input>
                         </label>

                    </div>

               </td>
          </tr>

     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes @dippas. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use differents names for your buttons.

For example call the first radio button "used1" and so on and it will work